# use node-deeplink with nestjs

Tags: express, nestjs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-deep-links

i alread  try add to main.ts but still not work

how i can use this lib with nestjs

```
app.get(
  '/deeplink',
  deeplink({
    fallback: 'https://cupsapp.com',
    android_package_name: 'com.citylifeapps.cups',
    ios_store_link:
      'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cups-unlimited-coffee/id556462755?mt=8&uo=4',
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define a GET endpoint and pass the parameters to the deeplink function.

```js
import * as deeplink from 'node-deeplink';
```

```js
@Get('verify-email')
  verifyEmail(@Next() next, @Req() req, @Res() res) {
    return deeplink({
      fallback: 'https://www.example.com',
      android_package_name: 'com.example.app',
      ios_store_link:
        'https://apps.apple.com/do/app/example/id3154673031',
    })(req, res, next);
  }
```